# Django queryset result is wrong for the test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

My model is:

```
class AndroidOffer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    # ...
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

And the following code (I skipped previous filtering):

```
active_offers = active_offers.filter(countries__in=[country])
```

It generates this SQL query:

```
SELECT "offers_androidoffer"."id", "offers_androidoffer"."name", "offers_androidoffer"."title", "offers_androidoffer"."is_for_android", "offers_androidoffer"."is_for_ios", "offers_androidoffer"."url", "offers_androidoffer"."icon", "offers_androidoffer"."cost", "offers_androidoffer"."quantity", "offers_androidoffer"."hourly_completions", "offers_androidoffer"."is_active", "offers_androidoffer"."description", "offers_androidoffer"."comment", "offers_androidoffer"."priority", "offers_androidoffer"."offer_type", "offers_androidoffer"."package_name", "offers_androidoffer"."is_search_install", "offers_androidoffer"."search_query", "offers_androidoffer"."launches" FROM "offers_androidoffer" INNER JOIN "offers_androidoffer_platform_versions" ON ("offers_androidoffer"."id" = "offers_androidoffer_platform_versions"."androidoffer_id") INNER JOIN "offers_androidoffer_countries" ON ("offers_androidoffer"."id" = "offers_androidoffer_countries"."androidoffer_id") WHERE ("offers_androidoffer"."is_active" = True AND "offers_androidoffer"."quantity" > 0 AND NOT ("offers_androidoffer"."id" IN (SELECT U0."offer_id" FROM "offers_androidofferstate" U0 WHERE (U0."device_id" = 1 AND (U0."state" = 3 OR U0."state" = 4)))) AND NOT ("offers_androidoffer"."package_name" IN (SELECT V0."package_name" FROM "applications_app" V0 INNER JOIN "applications_deviceapp" V1 ON (V0."id" = V1."app_id") WHERE (V1."device_id" IN (SELECT U0."device_id" FROM "users_userdevice" U0 WHERE U0."user_id" = 2) AND NOT (V0."package_name" IN (SELECT U2."package_name" FROM "offers_androidofferstate" U0 INNER JOIN "offers_androidoffer" U2 ON (U0."offer_id" = U2."id") WHERE (U0."device_id" = 1 AND (U0."state" = 0 OR U0."state" = 1 OR U0."state" = 2))))))) AND "offers_androidoffer_platform_versions"."platformversion_id" IN (14) AND "offers_androidoffer_countries"."country_id" IN (6252001)) ORDER BY "offers_androidoffer"."priority" DESC;
```

If I run this query in Postgresql console, it will return 0 rows, but `active_offers` has 4 results (all rows in table), like if I remove `AND "offers_androidoffer_countries"."country_id" IN (6252001)` statement.

I run this code from tests (APITestCase.client -> DRF view -> filter queryset). Django version is 2.0.2.

Why it ignores country filtering?

**UPD.** I've just checked with simple `TestCase` (test -> filter queryset) test and it returns correct number of rows. So, problem exists only with DRF testing.

**UPD 2.** Testcase where it works incorrectly:

```
class AndroidOffersListTests(APITestCase):
    fixtures = [
        'geo/fixtures/cities.json',
        'offers/fixtures/users.json',
        'offers/fixtures/devices.json',
        'offers/fixtures/geo.json',
        'offers/fixtures/apps.json',
        'offers/fixtures/offers.json',
    ]

    def test_list_offers_1(self):
        user_device = UserDevice.objects.get(pk=1)

        token = AndroidOffersListTests.get_token_for_device(user_device)
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {}'.format(token))

        url = AndroidOffersListTests.get_url(user_device)
        response = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_200_OK, response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(0, len(response.data)) # result is 4
```

View code:

```
class AndroidOffersView(ListAPIView):
    model = AndroidOffer
    serializer_class = AndroidOffersSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        device = UserDevice.get_from_request(self.request)
        if device is None:
            raise PermissionDenied()

        return AndroidOffer.get_offers_for_device(device)
```

get_offers_for_device:

```
@staticmethod
def get_offers_for_device(user_device):
    active_offers = AndroidOffer.get_active_offers()

    # Filter completed
    completed_states = AndroidOfferState.get_completed_for_device(user_device)
    completed_offers_ids = completed_states.values_list('offer__pk', flat=True)

    active_offers = active_offers.exclude(pk__in=completed_offers_ids)

    # Filter apps already installed on the user's devices
    apps = user_device.user.apps

    # Remove packages that are in progress
    in_progress_states = AndroidOfferState.get_in_progress_for_device(user_device)
    in_progress_packages = in_progress_states.values_list('offer__package_name', flat=True)
    apps = apps.exclude(package_name__in=in_progress_packages)

    packages = apps.values_list('package_name', flat=True)

    active_offers = active_offers.exclude(package_name__in=packages)

    # Filter by platform version
    active_offers = active_offers.filter(platform_versions__in=[user_device.device.version])

    # Filter by country
    country = user_device.last_geo_record.country
    if country is not None:
        active_offers = active_offers.filter(countries__in=[country])

    return active_offers
```

Test case where it works fine:

```
class AndroidOffersListTests(TestCase):
    fixtures = [
        'geo/fixtures/cities.json',
        'offers/fixtures/users.json',
        'offers/fixtures/devices.json',
        'offers/fixtures/geo.json',
        'offers/fixtures/apps.json',
        'offers/fixtures/offers.json',
    ]

    def test_list_offers_1(self):
        user_device = UserDevice.objects.get(pk=1)

        offers = AndroidOffer.get_offers_for_device(user_device)

        self.assertEqual(0, offers.count()) # 0 — thats ok
```

**UPD 3:** when I'm running the same request in browser, it works fine:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your test case?

Comment: @kevswanberg done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said this response is **incorrect**:

```
self.assertEqual(0, len(response.data)) # result is 4
```

But you also say this JSON response is **correct**:

```
{
    "count": 0,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": []
}
```

You're using a *paginated API* here.  The length of `4` is due to the number of keys present in the deserialized json:

```
>>> len(json.loads('{"count": 0, "next": null, "previous": null, "results": []}'))
4
```

Note that you don't need to actually call `json.loads` yourself, the DRF framework has already handled that for you when preparing the response - i.e. `response.data` will be a dict already.

In the "Test case where it works fine", you're dealing with the queryset directly:

```
self.assertEqual(0, offers.count()) # 0 — thats ok
                         ^
                         |____ here you go to the database, no serializer!
```

If you want to check the number of results, from the paginated JSON api, then you'll need to drill down that page:

```
len_results = len(response.data['results'])
```

For a test that is expected to return 0 results, this is sufficient.  But take care - if you ever have tests which you expect to generate more results than the page size (configured in the settings), you may also want to check the `count`, and `next` values.  You'll have to make additional requests to subsequent pages to collect all results.

Comment: You're right. I did not take into account that response is dict.

Answer (score 0):

`field__in` checks if the field is in the list that you pass in to it.

You can get your desired behavior with just this

```
active_offers = active_offers.filter(countries=country)
```

Comment: It generates correct (maybe not the best one, but correct) SQL query. The question now is why it ignores "AND" clause in queryset. Please, see my update.